# How to fix Runtime error while downloading file on android using Kotlin?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, file, download, app-inventor

I am getting Runtime error while downloading file using Kotlin in android here in this code i am using thread and if i don't use it then app is crashing and I don't know why i am getting this error well I am new at Kotlin so sorry for any trouble, and also I am trying to make extension here for **mit app inventor** and i am new at this also ....

I use a **SimpleFunction** annotation to create a simple function block that will run another function ( download function ) here is SimpleFunction's code :

`

```
@SimpleFunction(description = "Simple download block")
fun simpleDownload(url: String, path: String) {
    val paths = if (path.endsWith("/")){
        "${path}${getFileName(url)}"
    }else{
        "${path}/${getFileName(url)}"
    }
    thread(
        start = true,
        isDaemon = true
    ){
    download(url, path)
    }
}
```

Here I use thread but it is crashing the application but when i don't use threading then i am getting Runtime error without any other data but i am able to create the file but don't able to save the stream content here is download function code ( Here **getFileName** function help to get filename from url )

`

```
fun download(link: String, path: String): Long {

    val url = URL(link)

    val connection = url.openConnection()

    connection.connect()

    url.openStream().use { input ->

        FileOutputStream(File(path)).use { output ->

            val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)

            var bytesRead = input.read(buffer)

            var bytesCopied = 0L

            while (bytesRead >= 0) {

                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)

                bytesCopied += bytesRead

                bytesRead = input.read(buffer)

            }

            return bytesCopied

        }

    }

}
```

Well i can use Download Manager which is already available and its easy to download file from there but I don't want because it did't support some features which i needs so please help me to fix this issue :-(

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Nothing application is closing don't know why :-(

And if i don't use thread then its throwing runtime error with no text means without any logs only runtime error

Comment: If you find out how to look at the relevant logs, you should be able to see the exact error message (and probably the associated stack trace), which will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The App Inventor development environment currently does not support Kotlin. Use Java instead. See also the [App Inventor Extensions document](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/extensions.html). Alternatively use the [Rush development environment](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/rush-a-new-and-improved-way-of-building-extensions/28699?u=taifun), which also supports Kotlin.

And for creating extensions please follow the [naming conventions for extension developers](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/naming-conventions-for-extension-developers/22186).

Comment: oki but i am using Rush with kotlin .....

And also i just fix it it was because of tost message

Comment: in this case you forgot to mention, that you are using Rush... you said, you found the problem... what about writing an answer to provide the solution to your issue then?

Answer (score 0):

The App Inventor development environment currently does not support Kotlin. Use Java instead. See also the App Inventor Extensions document. Alternatively use the Rush development environment, which also supports Kotlin.

And for creating extensions please follow the naming conventions for extension developers.